# ICopyHook yes to all

Tags: c++, windows-shell

I've implemented the Windows Shell interface ICopyHook to prompt the user when they move or rename network folders, to verify if they really want to perform this operation.  It passes in the source filename and the destination, and I have to return ID_YES, ID_NO, or ID_CANCEL.  The problem comes in when they are moving multiple folders: each folder triggers a separate call to ICopyHook, and they get a prompt for each folder.

I want to implement a way to say "yes to all".  I can keep my own state internally, and I could just record that we're currently in a "yes to all" and return ID_YES for each operation, but somehow it has to know to reset when the current move operation completes.

If each move happened instantaneously, I could give the "yes to all" status a timeout, but if the move is happening across drives, it could take any amount of time.  In other words, it could prompt for one folder, and take 2 hours to copy it, and the next one prompts after 2 hours, but it's still part of the same move operation.

Is there any way to implement a "yes to all" that will reset when the current operation completes?

Comment: Assuming you're using ICopyHook::CopyCallback, have you tried using the FOF_MULTIDESTFILES flag that is passed through the wFlags parameter?  That would allow you to determine if one or more files are being copied.

Comment: In other words, you have no idea when the user starts a new copy so you could reset that variable.  Yeah, tricky problem.  SetWinEventHook() could technically work.

Comment: You could probably do it with a clipboard copy/paste by inspecting the `IDataObject` on the clipboard to see which files are involved, but that wouldn't work for drag & drop.